# Robocopy to Shared Drive of Google Drive with G: Disk in Windows 10

Tags: google-drive-api, migration, robocopy, google-drive-shared-drive, shared-directory

I need help to migrate a great amount of files from a server (identified as \\server\folder) to a Shared Drive, mapped on Windows 10 using Google Drive For Desktop (the path looks like this: G:\Shared drives\SharedDriveName\Folder).

How can I do it?

I used Robocopy, I checked the log file too, it says that the migration should be completed, but I can't see the files in Google Drive.

Can you please tell me the correct script I should use? In one case, I need to overwrite the files and to add the files that are missing in Google Drive.
In the other case I need to add the files that are missing in Google Drive.

I tried to use Robocopy and rClone.

A lot of files are missing in the destination after I used rClone